# Push notifications from web server (php & mysql) to iOS app

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode, apple-push-notifications

i am working on messaging application in which i want to send notifications for a new message from web server to iOS device. I have no idea how to achieve this. Could anyone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at this link https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=push-notifications) from Apple? What code have you tried? Is there anything specific we can help you with?

Comment: i want to configure my web server for push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easy achieved with using [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) ([Firebase cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/index)). It supports both iOS/Android platforms. Allows broadcasted Push Notifications. iOS/Android app subscribes to a "topic". GCM/FCM sends push to the "topic" and all subscribed apps receive push notifications. Firebase Cloud Messaging is new version of GCM and developed to replace Google Cloud Messaging. 
Google recommends to use FCM on new projects. But on my project we still use GCM, it is enough for our business requirements.

Your server can trigger FCM endpoint for sending Push Notification.